# jQuery UI datepicker: move to the next field after date select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've created a web form that uses the jQuery-UI datepicker.  When a date is selected, the focus on the textbox where the date is entered is lost.

I would like to make the focus either stay in the datepicker-enabled textbox or else move to the text element on my web form.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      $(this).focus();
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HNeF9/

Answer (score 1):

upon selecting a date, the onClose event is run... so you could put some code in there, and that could focus where you want to

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onClose: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```